# How to make Font size equal to 15 in Terminal on Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, terminal

Here are the configuration settings for the Terminal app in Yosemite.

[image]

It shows that I can set font size to the distinct values given in Terminal. How can I set it to some other in-between value like in my case, I want to set it to "15"?

Comment: My two cents - try iterm2. If there isn't any particular reason for sticking to Terminal - use iterm2.

Comment: My two cents - try terminal. If there isn't any particular reason for sticking to iTerm2 - use terminal.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is what I did in OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

Terminal (menu) > Preferences... > Settings > Select the target Profile > Text > Change... (button)

This brought up the Fonts window shown in the image below.

[image: Fonts1]

I then resized the Fonts dialog box vertically until the Size text window appeared and entered 15, as shown in the image below.

[image: Fonts2]

Comment: You just won my heart buddy. Really thanks for it. That was awesome.

Comment: It would be lovely if there were a way to do it from the command line

Comment: discoverable UI 

Answer (score 22):

You can also add custom values for font sizes. From the Font window, click the gear in the upper left, and choose "Edit Sizes".

[image]

Then, enter your value.

[image]

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer, as you cannot do the currently accepted answer anymore.

Comment: Both answers worked for me in 2022 with Monterey (macOS Version 12.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

Optionally, you can increase and decrease font size for bash with,

```
Command and the Plus (+) key
Command and the Minus (-) key
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ventura 13.3.1, there was no slider. I needed to add a new, discrete size.

[image: "Edit Sizes" setting]
[image: "New Size"]